# time automaticly an indicator for 6NF

Tags: time, relational-database, 3nf

is this correct:
As soon as entities loose their attribute-invariance through time,( maybe independently e.g only some attribute then again only one attribute), the only way to correctly normalize is with 6NF.

3NF is a special form of 6NF. But I can't image 3NF when time variance comes into the game.

Answer (score 3):

> As soon as
>   entities loose their
>   attribute-invariance through time,(
>   maybe independently e.g only some
>   attribute then again only one
>   attribute), the only way to correctly
>   normalize is with 6NF.

6NF isn't the *only* way. I suspect that 5NF is much more commonly used than 6NF as a method of recording history-preserving data - by making a timestamp or time range part of the keys. 6NF has the advantage of not requiring you to repeat every attribute each time one attribute changes. That's not a kind of redundancy that 5NF is concerned with, so a 5NF model of time-varying data is still "correct" according to 5NF - it's just that it may preserve more dependencies than 6NF does.